# dynamically generate NSPredicate from an NSArray

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a large number of different NSObject types that all have different properties and I am trying to abstract out a single method that will allow me to filter the NSArrays of the objects by simply passing in an NSArray of properties I wish to filter on. The number keys I filter on vary from possibly 1 to whatever.

Here is an example of the filtering NSArray

> ```
> NSArray *filterBy = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                        @"ManufacturerID",
>                        @"CustomerNumber",nil];
> ```

These keys also exist in the objects of my NSArray I am filtering, so basically this would need to generate something like this:

> ```
> NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@ AND %K == %@",
>                        [filterBy objectAtIndex:0], 
>                        [items valueForKey: [filterBy objectAtindex:0],
>                        [filterBy objectAtIndex:1], 
>                        [items valueForKey: [filterBy objectAtIndex:1]];
> ```

Which would generate something like: `ManufacturerID==18 AND CustomerNumber=='WE543'`

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy.  Check it out:

```
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *filterKey in filterBy) {
  NSString *filterValue = [items valueForKey:filterKey];
  NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", filterKey, filterValue];
  [subpredicates addObject:p];
}
NSPredicate *final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
```

Comment: awesome - I knew there had to be something like this for me to use!